# INFL as Maximal Projection

Tags: syntax

Argument that advanced for the emergence of INFL as the maximum projection in sentential construction under the X-bar theory

Answer (score 1):

It's not maximal.  The scope of a past tense does not extend past the clause in which it appears, thus in

> Tony died. His children carry on.

the "carry on" is not interpreted as being in the past tense.

But in

> If Tony died, his gas station would still make a profit.  His grocery would continue in business.

the "would" of the last sentence is interpreted as being in the scope of the conditional in the first sentence.

So, the scope of an if-clause is wider than that of a tense.  The projection of an if-clause extends beyond a clause, so it is wider than that of a tense.  So a tense is not in a maximal projection.